# Как запретить вызов выбранного фрагмента?

Tags: java, android

```
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private boolean fragmentselect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TestFragment fragment_test = new TestFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_test = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction_test.replace(R.id.frame, fragment_test);
    fragmentTransaction_test.commit();
    fragmentselect = true;


    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

          drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

          switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.test:
               if(fragmentselect = true) 
                  return false;
               else {
                  TestFragment fragment_test = new TestFragment();
                  android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction_test = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                  fragmentTransaction_test.replace(R.id.frame, fragment_test);
                  fragmentTransaction_test.commit();
                  fragmentselect = true;
               }
             case R.id.test2: {
                  // Код фрагмента
                  fragmentselect = false;       
             }
```

В чем ошибка? Как лучше осуществлять данную проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта конструкция очень странная:

> if(fragmentselect = true)

Тут вы или опечатались, забыв ещё одно "=" поставить или ещё чего... Попробуйте так:

```
if(fragmentselect)
```